# Facebook PHP SDK v3.1.1 - Post message on page wall as the page offline

Tags: php, facebook, offline, facebook-wall

I'm trying to post a message on a page's wall as the page itself without any user connected.

For now, the first part works fine, but I need a connected user to do it. I've heard I need a seesion ID to do it offline, but I don't know how to get it and how to use it.

For now, my code is:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $appID, 'secret' => $appSecret));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

try 
{
    $pageInfo = $facebook->api("/{$pageID}?fields=access_token");
    if(!empty($pageInfo['access_token'])) 
    {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $pageInfo['access_token'],
            'message'       => $message
        );
        $postID = $facebook->api("/{$pageID}/feed", 'post', $args);
    }
} 
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($e); echo '</pre>';
    $user = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the offline_access permission set, then you can do what you need. Check this out it will show you what to do: http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will be removing offline_access permission, they are now allowing the option to use access_tokens with a long-lived expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `publish_stream` permissions.

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

Besides to post as the page (not user) ask for `manage_pages`.

```
var $permissions_needed = 'manage_pages,publish_stream';
```

How to login:

```
$this->login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => $this->permissions_needed,
            'display' => 'page'
        )
);
```